# gem install mongrel fails with ruby 1.9.1

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mongrel, ruby-1.9

I initiated myself into rails development yesterday.
I installed ruby 1.9.1, rubygems and rails.
Running `gem install mongrel` worked fine and ostensibly installed mongrel too. I am slightly puzzled because:

- script/server starts webrick by default
- `which mongrel` returns nothing
- `locate mongrel` returns lots of entries like

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.0.1
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.0.1/lib
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.0.1/lib/mongrel
.
.
.
/usr/local/bin/mongrel_rails
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/mongrel-1.1.5.gem
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/doc/actionpack-2.3.2/rdoc/files/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1_0/rack/handler/evented_mongrel_rb.html
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/doc/actionpack-2.3.2/rdoc/files/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1_0/rack/handler/mongrel_rb.html
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/doc/actionpack-2.3.2/rdoc/files/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1_0/rack/handler/swiftiplied_mongrel_rb.html
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/handler/evented_mongrel.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/handler/mongrel.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/handler/swiftiplied_mongrel.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.1.5
.
.
.
```

Does look like I have mongrel installed (both the default installation and my custom install). So why doesn't which mongrel return something.

Also trying to reinstall mongrel using `gem install mongrel` returns throws its own set of exceptions:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mongrel:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb install mongrel
checking for main() in -lc... yes
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-darwin9.7.0 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=1 -O2 -g -Wall -Wno-parentheses  -fno-common -pipe -fno-common  -o http11.o -c http11.c
http11.c: In function 'http_field':
http11.c:77: error: 'struct RString' has no member named 'ptr'
http11.c:77: error: 'struct RString' has no member named 'len'
http11.c:77: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect
http11.c:77: warning: statement with no effect
http11.c: In function 'header_done':
http11.c:172: error: 'struct RString' has no member named 'ptr'
http11.c:174: error: 'struct RString' has no member named 'ptr'
http11.c:176: error: 'struct RString' has no member named 'ptr'
http11.c:177: error: 'struct RString' has no member named 'len'
http11.c: In function 'HttpParser_execute':
http11.c:298: error: 'struct RString' has no member named 'ptr'
http11.c:299: error: 'struct RString' has no member named 'len'
make: *** [http11.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like [other people are having problems running Mongrel](https://web.archive.org/web/20130121164448/http://isitruby19.com/mongrel) on Ruby 1.9.

The comment by Ami Mahloof seems like it might be a possible fix:

> Here’s What you need to do in order to fix it
>
> here’s the updated instructions:
>
> 1) cd /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/ext/http11
>
> 2) sudo vi / mate on http11.c and:
>
> replace line 77 with
>
> for(ch = RSTRING_PTR(f), end = ch + RSTRING_LEN(f); ch < end; ch++) {
>
> replace line 172 with
>
> colon = strchr(RSTRING_PTR(temp), ':');
>
> replace line 174 with
>
> rb_hash_aset(req, global_server_name, rb_str_substr(temp, 0, colon - RSTRING_PTR(temp)));
>
> replce line 176,177
>
> rb_str_substr(temp, colon - RSTRING_PTR(temp)+1,
>   RSTRING_LEN(temp)));
>
> replace lines 298 299
>
> dptr = RSTRING_PTR(data);
>
> dlen = RSTRING_LEN(data);
>
> 3) save the file, close the vi / textmate
>
> 4) sudo ruby extconf.rb && sudo make && sudo make install
>
> 5) cd ../../lib/mongrel
>   (or the full path “/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel”
>
> 6) mate / sudo vi handlers.rb
>
> 7) fix the case statements in
>
> On lines 208-212, change instances of “: false” to “then false”
>
> 8) sudo gem install gem_plugin (else mongrel may hang)
>
> done!

Comment: the site is down, can you please paste the comment / contents here, thanks

Answer (score 47):

You can install mongrel 1.2 prerelease with `sudo gem install mongrel --pre`:

```
$ sudo gem1.9 install mongrel --pre
> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
> Successfully installed mongrel-1.2.0.pre2
> 1 gem installed
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a compilation issue so it’s easier to do this:

```
git clone git://github.com/mongrel/mongrel.git

cd mongrel/ext/http/
```

Now edit the `http11.c`:

```
#ifndef RSTRING_PTR
#define RSTRING_PTR(s) (RSTRING(s))
#endif
#ifndef RSTRING_LEN
#define RSTRING_LEN(s) (RSTRING(s))
#endif
```

Save it and now from the same directory do the following:

```
sudo ruby extconf.rb && sudo make && sudo make install
```

Done!

Answer (score 2):

You Can Force To Install mongrel like this

sudo gem install mongrel -v 1.2.0.pre2 -- --with-cflags=\"-O2 -pipe -march=native -w\"

This Solve the issue.